# How do I implement multiple colours on a signature pad in xamarin android?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, colors, signature

I want to allow the user to write in multiple colours on a signature pad. The idea is that they click on a radio button and it changes the colour. Currently, when the user clicks on a radio button, it changes the colour of the strokes that are already on the signature pad. How do I make it so that the original colours stay there but the user can also write in a different colour?

Comment: you will need to download the source from github and make the necessary changes to do what you want

Comment: What source is that please?

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/SignaturePad

Comment: This doesnt help

Comment: The component's API doesn't allow for what you want to do.  Having access to the source allows you to make any changes you want.  How does that not help?